# Apache RewriteRule help needed

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite

application uses url like `http://www.mydomain.com/item/3193.html` to select and show proper record from mysql database.

just to mention, application is written in php, hosted on apache web server..

in fact that should be `http://www.mydomain.com/item.html/3193.html`, but in .htaccess i have RewriteRule that helps me to treat it like `http://www.mydomain.com/item/3193.html`

but on the new server that RewriteRule, from some reason does not work. as i said, it is defined in .htaccess with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#some conditions here
RewriteRule ^item/(.*) item.html/$1
#more conditions here
```

so, it works on old server. it (looks like ?) that it's not working on new server...

so, first of all, i will check with hosting provider if rewrite rules are allowed on server.

also, if they are (and i guess that they are), can i change syntax for this RewriteRule, to get ability i need?

thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more likely that you don't have permission to setup .htaccess files. Try to do some basic things like directory listing (without having an index{htm,html,php} or any default page you might have) using `Options Indexes`

If you are unable to see directory contents, the `AllowOverride` is set to None (or something restrictive) and that is your problem. It must at least be set to `AllowOverride FileInfo` and `Options FollowSymLinks` is also required. Talk to your provider if you really need it (*).

In case you can view the directory listing, then you don't have the required options, and then again, talk to your provider.

(*) RewriteRules are OK inside an .htaccess in a staging or development server where you are trying to get a job done fast without restarting apache many times. If you can, be sure to move them up to virtualhost configuration once your on production.

Comment: syntax in my .htaccess is ok, right? i can setup and use .htaccess, but it doesen't work for RewriteRule... i talked to hosting provider, and he confirmed that i can use .htaccess to write my own rules...

Comment: Yes syntax is OK as long as the working directory is efectively the root of your site. Otherwise RewriteBase should make that clear (i.e. RewriteBase /some/path/). Ask them what is the configuration for AllowOverride and Options. That should give us a hint on why they do not work.